# Long delay in receiving some messages

Tags: ios, messages, sms

Yesterday morning I received a series of messages (some personal, others of account validation) that were 36 hours old, while during this time I continued to exchange without any particular problem.

Likewise today, in the middle of an important conversation, I stopped receiving messages, I tried an online service to send an SMS to my number and I didn't receive it. After restarting the phone, the online service works but I still haven't received the messages from earlier.
I can't afford to wait several days waiting.

**How to what messages I haven't received yet and how to prevent it from happening again?**

**Note.** I was under iOS 14 Beta 4, I deleted the developer profile to see if I could go back to iOS 13 but now it just says "iOS 14.0, your software is up to date".

Comment: So… what do you actually ned help with? There's no question here, just a series of statements.

Comment: I thought it was pretty obvious, like knowing what messages I haven't received yet and how to prevent it from happening again. Thanks.

Comment: It could equally have been "How do I get back to iOS 13?" As iOS 14 is a beta, you need to report it to Apple.

Comment: I'll surely do but I was wondering if there was a solution but waiting for the next update hoping that it is a software issue and that the next Beta solves it.

Comment: I'm afraid this does run contra to the 'golden rule of beta testing'… never run a beta on any mission-critical machine. Wish you luck with the next beta :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there may bit a little more to say. I did not find a user with the same problem so it might not be related with the use of iOS 14.

Comment: Ask your SMS provider. sms does not have  guaranteed delivery